Intercepted route is too greedy, catching everything
With Nextjs 15 app router, on my website the urls of the posts look like that /rand123 (same pattern as Imgur, ex : /Uadca, /ade3a, etc...) I am trying to set up a modal / intercepted for this route so I did that :
app/
  ├── [post]/
  │   └── page.js
  ├── @modal/
  │   └── (.)[post]/
  │       └── page.js
  ├── contact/
  │   └── page.js
  └── gallery/
      └── page.js

The issue is that the modal is also catching the others routes like /contact, /gallery, /tags etc.. Altough these routes are working fine without the modal (if I go directly to /contact I see the contact page).
Any idea ?

try to nest the folder: app/[post]/@modal

Thank you I did app/[post]/@modal/page.js , app/[post]/page.js is intercepted but the new issue is that if I go directly to app/[post]/page.js its also intetercepted (my layout.js still return modal)
